# How to deduce an equation from this 3 Diophantine equations with 5 variables?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

I have three equations:

${m \choose 2} + nk = {x \choose 2}$

${n \choose 2} + mk = {y \choose 2}$

$x + y = m + n + k$

$m, n, k, x, y$ are natural numbers. I want to deduce from this 3 equations either $x = y$ or $m = n$. From where I got these equations makes me sure that this is only possible if $x = y$ and $m = n$. Just deducing either $x=y$ or $m=n$ is enough.

I can show that if I show that $x + y$ is not divisible by 3. So it will be enough if we can show that $x + y$ is not divisible by 3.

Comment: The solutions seem to be of the form $[m,n,k,x,y] = [a,a,4a+2,3a+1,3a+1]$ for $a$ a natural number and $a \geq 2$.

Comment: It seems that you are right, I just want to show that either $m = n$, or $x = y$

Comment: You might use this to transform your system into another system with variables, say, $a,b,c,d,e$, such that $a=b=c=d=e \geq 2$ are the only solutions of your new system. Maybe then showing that all unknowns in the new system have to be the same is easier than the problem you face now (just a thought, might or might not work).

Comment: I also can deduce that if I show that $x + y$ is not divisible by $3$, i.e. $x + y  !=  0  mod  3$

Comment: If k=0 is allowed it can not be shown that x=y or m=n has to hold. consider for example k=0 then m=x and n=y and all natural numbers are allowed for either of these pairs

Comment: @zen all the variables can only be natural numbers, so $k$ cannot be $0$

Comment: May i ask about the origin of this problem? Seems like some contest problem.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou no it's not a contest problem. I need this in my research project. The story is very long to discuss in this post.

Comment: @DavitSargsyan: I would suggest changing the title, by replacing "deduce an equation from" with "solve", since what you are asking is tantamount to finding all the solutions.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch but I am not asking to find all solutions, I just wanna show one of following, either $x=y$ or $m = n$. Or I wanna show that $x+y!=0mod3$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first two equalities imply $x>m$ and $y>n$ so one can substitute $x=m+X$, $y=n+Y$ and $k=X+Y$, with still $X,Y \in \mathbb N$:

${X \choose 2}=nX+nY-mX\tag{1}$

${Y \choose 2}=mX+mY-nY\tag{2}$

From (1) follows: $\quad m=n+n\frac{Y}{X}-\frac{1}{X}{X \choose 2}$,

then eliminate $m$ from (2): $\quad {Y \choose 2}+{X \choose 2}+\frac{Y}{X}{X \choose 2}=nX+nY+n\frac{Y^2}{X}$,

and finally: $\quad 2n=X-\frac{X^2+2XY}{X^2+XY+Y^2}$.

Clearly $X-2n=\frac{X^2+2XY+0Y^2}{X^2+XY+Y^2}\in(0,2)$, but since it is an integer it can only be $1$.

This proves that $X=2n+1$ and by symmetry $Y=2m+1$.
Substituting for $X$ and $Y$ in (1) or (2) finally yields $m=n$, so $X=Y$ and $x=y$.

Answer (score -2):

Rewrite the system of equations.

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&m(m-t)+2n(x+y-m-n)=x(x-t)\\&n(n-t)+2m(x+y-m-n)=y(y-t)\end{aligned}\right.$$

The solution of this system can be written as.

$$n=(-8a^3+12ba^2-6ab^2+2b^3)p+(4a^2-5ab+b^2)s$$

$$m=(8a^3+2ba^2-ab^2)p+(4a^2-5ab+b^2)s$$

$$t=(-8a^3+12ba^2-6ab^2+2b^3)p+(12a^2-6ab+3b^2)s$$

$$x=(10ba^2-5ab^2+4b^2)p-3(a-b)bs$$

$$y=(8a^3+8ba^2+2ab^2)p+3a(4a-b)s$$

And you can see that the linear Diophantine equation  $t=1$ Has no solutions in integers.

Comment: It isn't clear to me just what you claim to have proved.  The original equations do have solutions over the integers.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Has no solutions for  $t=1$.  I changed the task. Instead of solving the system. The task is reduced to finding solutions of linear equations.

Comment: $k=3,m=0,n=1,x=3,y=1$ and infinitely many other solutions.  You need to impose the positivity condition to eliminate the solutions.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay  Well, Yes. Of course. I didn't notice that...  $$t=(4a^2-2ab+b^2)(3s+(b-a)p)$$  Then other numbers to divide by a common factor.